# Why does adaptive-icon generated by Android Studio crop images so much to make unusable?

Tags: android, android-tv, android-icons, android-asset-studio

I used Android Studio's Asset Studio to generate TV banners:
[image]

Everything looks great in Asset Studio, but the generated adaptive-icon crops the image so much that it is unusable:
[image]

Here is what it looks like on Android TV:
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on how to remove the cropping?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @MisterDev21 Sorry for the late response. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70524880/355456

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since no one has answered the question since it was posted 9 months ago, let me try to answer it with my own solution.

Android Studio's Asset Studio to generates several file one of which is ic_banner.xml under directory mipmap-anydpi-v26:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_banner_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_banner_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

It shows the cropped image. I have modified it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@color/ic_banner_background"/>
    <foreground>
        <inset android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_banner_foreground"
            android:inset="12%"/>
    </foreground>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Now, the icon looks just like other TV app icons. I got the hint from [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e).

Comment: I've done as you did. It still crops my banner in home screen.